# VMware ESXi RDM Shared Disk and Multipathing

Tags: vmware-esxi, multipath, raw-disk

I have set up a RAW mapped storage device which is shared between 3 VMs. In the guest OSs the disk shows up fine but when I try to set up multipathing I can only see one path.

In the virtual machine properties when I select the new (raw mapped lun) disk and hit "manage paths" I can see the path list. The SCSI Controller is LSI Logic Parallel

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is the RDM connected to the VM(s)? What is the storage device?

Comment: A VM doesn't inherit the hosts multipathing config - i.e. if a LUN is presented to a host over 1000 paths it still only gets presented to the VM as over a single path - same goes for RDMs too iirc.